# Posting file content to a REST webservice along with other data in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jar

I have a REST webservice developed using java. I have a jar file which does some logic and writes some data to a file. My requirement is to send the data along with a couple of other data (other two data are just simple strings). How do i write the service part ?
1. Should i write the service so as to accept data as byte stream ? If so how do i send the file content from the jar to the service ?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Google `multipart` http requests

Comment: This question is too broad. What jar are you using ? what kind of file you want to send ? plain text ? media ? how does the REST service receive the requests ? how does it receive files and what does it do with it ? you should do some HW before you post a question here...

Comment: Hi alfasin, i am a newbie to the whole REST file upload part . The jar just wries a plain text which is to be sent  I am not sure how to handle the REST service  part.The service (resides in another PC) basically has to read the data and write the data to a file (filename also has to be sent along with the data)

Comment: As the first comment already said you will need to have your server side web interface support the multipart mime type to be able to support file upload via HTTP.  Then it is just a mater of what server side framework you are using.  Spring WebMVC for instance already has an API for this that just gives you the uploaded file as a file object.  Each API will handle this differently.

Comment: in the server side, what should be the consume type ? should it be @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)? I am not using any forms here. sorry of the question is stupid. i am looking through the multipart http as i type this